# The reason of the result of `re.findall(r'(.)*', 'aabc')` in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

the line `re.findall(r'(.)*', 'aabc')` will return ['c', ''] instead of ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', '']. Why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern says match one capturing group of one character `(.)` zero or more times `*`.

There are two matches with this pattern. First, it matches `'aabc'` as  `(.)` (a capturing group of a single character) four times. The result in `findall` for that will be the content of the captured group, which is `c`, since the last thing your group captures is `c`.

The second match found is the empty string (which is a match since `*` can mean "zero times"), in which case nothing is captured in the capturing group, and you get an empty string as a result.

If you want the result `['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', '']`, you could use

```
re.findall(r'.?', 'aabc')
```

which is "match any single character optionally".